# Update function on Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

How make an Update function in Three.js, like in Unity3d?
I mean, that i create an object:

var torus = new THREE.Mesh(
          new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(60,20,100),
          reflectionMaterial
        );

and when i click on the body, i change a reflectionMaterial. But the image don't change, i see  a not changed reflectionMaterial (last figure). Always redrawing a render image???
Thank's for attention. Sorry for my English (I'm from Ukrainian).

P.S.: I work with Three.js onn my netbook and on (not my) notebook. On netbook i don't see a shaders. Why?? Did the Three.js support Shader Model number 3 and 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are having issues changing a material after you click on something? You may need to change a flag depending on if you already have a material or not, there are some dependencies - check the link below:

```
material.needsUpdate = true;
```

There is an article on [How to update things in Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates)